# What is the difference between "Academy for" and "Academy of"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

It appears that both "Academy for" and "Academy of" are in use (even though the latter returns far more Google hits). Could anyone help me in nuancing the two use cases?

Specifically - would you say "Academy for Project Management" or rather "Academy of Project Management"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious difference is when *academy for* points to the people (or other entities) who attend the academy, as is the case for the *[Hastings Leadership Academy **for** Women](https://worklifelaw.org/womens-leadership/hastings-leadership-academy-for-women-hlaw/)* (training for women in the field of Law) or the *[Academy **for** Grassroots Organizations](http://www.academygo.com/)* (training for activist organizations).

Other than that, the best I can offer is that *academy **of*** seems to be reserved for big picture topics -- [Academy of Sciences](https://www.calacademy.org/), [Academy of Art](https://www.academyart.edu/), [National Academy of Engineering](https://www.nae.edu/) -- while *academy **for*** appears to be more for specific areas of study or interest -- [Academy for Caregiving Excellence](https://www.academyforcaregiving.com/), [Academy for Dog Trainers](https://academyfordogtrainers.com/), [Academy for Eating Disorders](https://www.aedweb.org/home).

Unfortunately, this is certainly not absolute:  [Academy **for** Dance](https://www.academyfordance.com/) versus [Academy **of** Dance](http://www.sunsetacademyofdance.com/), [Academy **for** the Arts](https://www.valleyacademyarts.org/) versus [Academy **of** the Arts](https://www.fjuhsd.org/domain/1025), etc.

I suspect it's really a matter of personal style.